# Unable to run app - "The target device does not support the 'run-as' command"

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Running Android Studio on a Macbook for the first time and I'm getting this error. The program does not start on my device, I just get a crash message.

On Android Studio, I get "The target device does not support the 'run-as' command" and when I plug this into google I get no results. I get a "Learn More" section though which points to this link under the heading "About Instant Run": https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html?utm_medium=android-studio#instant-run.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Can you screenshot? What device are you using? What's your minSDK? What's your devices API/Version? Edit the question answering these questions otherwise we can't help you, then I'll remove the downvote if you remind me after you edit

Answer (score 3):

I recently upgraded to AS 2.2 and this message suddenly appeared today.
Restarting Studio caused this message to disappear.

But the build in general seemed slow - so I used the **adb commands** to stop and start the server and now it seems **Instant run** is working better

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

my phone is Moto G x1032 w lollipop

Comment: Just restarting Android Studio worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after rooting my device and the other answer didn't solve it. 
When I ran adb run-as command in the terminal I kept getting

```
    Could not set Capabilities: operation not permitted.
```

It's a permissions issue. You have to change permissions on run-as file in /system/bin folder. This solved it for me (needs root access):

```
    1. remount /system rw
    2. chmod 4750 /system/bin/run-as
    3. remount /system ro
```

If running custom recovery:

```
    1. reboot to recovery
    2. find the mount system and check it (make sure 'mount system as read-only' is unchecked)
    3. open a terminal and type: adb shell
    4. type: chmod 4750 /system/bin/run-as
    5. uncheck the System mount and reboot!
```

See here issue 58373: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373